# How can I override the @context when loading json-ld in Jena

Tags: jena, json-ld, hl7-fhir

I am loading a JSON-LD document using Jena:

```
  Model mj = RDFDataMgr.loadModel([filename]);
```

The actual content being loaded is here: http://build.fhir.org/account-example.jsonld

Jena goes off and resolves the context, and returns an error (LOADING_REMOTE_CONTEXT_FAILED - lovely suppression of the actual cause in the Jena code :-(). But I need to override the context anyway, and use a different source, because I am doing the build for what will be posted at build.fhir.org, and I need to use my local versions instead. I can't see how to override the context resolution

Alternatively, I could use the loading method documented here: https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java#code-example - but I have no idea how to get to a Jena graph from there (and I haven't figured out how make the custom resolution work in my Eclipse context either)

How can I get to a Jena graph using a context defined in code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think Jena devs are subscribed to the relevant tag RSS streams. They might weigh in on the clarity of `LOADING_REMOTE_CONTEXT_FAILED` error. But it seems pretty clear to me.
2. In order to override the context, you can use [`read(Model model, String uri, Context context)`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/RDFDataMgr.html#read-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model-java.lang.String-org.apache.jena.sparql.util.Context-) method. `ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()` will create a intance of a `Model` that you can pass as a first argument. See more examples here: https://github.com/apache/jena/tree/master/jena-arq/src-examples/arq/examples/riot
3. Alternative library is not Jena-compatible (nor RDF4J, which strikes me as rather silly), so there is no easy way to use it with Jena-dependent code.
4. Finally, you provided the code example for getting a model but now mention a graph – there is a method for that as well: [`read(Graph graph, String uri, Context context)`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/RDFDataMgr.html#read-org.apache.jena.graph.Graph-java.lang.String-org.apache.jena.sparql.util.Context-).

Comment: try { /* stuff */ } catch (final Exception e) { throw new JsonLdError(JsonLdError.Error.LOADING_REMOTE_CONTEXT_FAILED, url); } hides the cause of the context failing to load. Wrong address? wrong configuration? http authentication? missing CORS? wrong content type? So many things to guess at, no hints from the exception. If the Jena devs are reading.... I guess I just to have to actually use the source not, get the jars....

Comment: as for the .read() - thanks for the pointer, but I can't find any examples showing how to use the context to solve my problem. I guess I'll just have to walk the source

Comment: Sounds related https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1178 - you could ask on Jena users list. Not everyone subscribes on StackOverflow.